# Automaticaly add data-fancybox attribute to img wrapper using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to add `data-fancybox="gallery"` to all my `<a>` wrapper.

I have this code, it actually wrap all `<img>` with an `<a>` and get the src.

```
$("img").each(function () {
 $(this).wrap($('<a/>', {
    href: $(this).attr('src'),
    selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]',
 }));
});
```

I would like to replace the `selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]',` by `data-fancybox="gallery"`... I can't find out how to do this.

Thanks for your help folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr(key, value)` method to set attribute value

```
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap($('<a/>', {
            href: $(this).attr('src')
        }).attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery'));
});
```